# Replacing recursive function with simpler loop

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm new to the concept of recursion. I've been practicing JavaScript with some codes from javascript30.com. I've stumbled upon the below mention function:

```
function peep() {
    const time = randomTime(200, 1000); 
    const hole = randomHole(holes);
    hole.classList.add('up');
    setTimeout(() => {
      hole.classList.remove('up');
      if (!timeUp) peep();
    }, time);
  }
```

Link to full code: https://codepen.io/luckyseven444/pen/bXqXbP (code is running ok in my PC)

Is it possible to form a simple loop rather than the recursive function peep() mentioned above? I mean I want to replace the second peep() inside setTimeout function.

Thanks

Comment: Simple loop? well if you have a loop there will not be a delay

Comment: i'm less concerned on render time/memory efficiency for the time being, since i'm learning different ways to make same output as a beginner. the above code seems bit harder for me. i need a easy way out

Comment: It is not the render time, it would be the fact that the loop would run and all of the things will be shown at once.

Comment: You can just execute your `peep` function within `setInterval` callback

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist, you can create an `async` function, wrap `setTimeout` with a `Promise`, await the `Promise` and add a loop:

```js
async function test() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log('before setTimeout', i);
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('timeout elapsed', i);
      resolve();
    }, 1000));
  }
}

test();
```